# SVG create element with Javascript and no display img

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying do something with javascript + svg

I want, when click grid I want create an image inside that grid/squarex... I am trying another questions solutions of stackoverflow, but I don't understand the problem, the image not showing and no errors, any idea?

This is the javascript + svg code I tried. I have no idea what is wrong.

```html
  <body>
  <div id="tablero"  style="">
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    document.createSvg = function(tagName) {
        var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        return this.createElementNS(svgNS, tagName);
    };
    
    var numberPerSide = 20;
    var size = 10;
    var pixelsPerSide = 400;
    
    
    var eldiv = 0;
    var estado = 0;
    var tipo = "0";   
    
    // create grid
    var grid = function(numberPerSide, size, pixelsPerSide, colors) {
        var svg = document.createSvg("svg");
        svg.setAttribute("width", pixelsPerSide);
        svg.setAttribute("height", pixelsPerSide);
        svg.setAttribute("viewBox", [0, 0, numberPerSide * size, numberPerSide * size].join(" "));
        
        // create each box
        for(var i = 0; i < numberPerSide; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < numberPerSide; j++) {
              var color1 = colors[(i+j) % colors.length];
              var color2 = colors[(i+j+1) % colors.length];  
              var g = document.createSvg("g");
              g.setAttribute("transform", ["translate(", i*size, ",", j*size, ")"].join(""));
              var number = numberPerSide * i + j;
              var box = document.createSvg("rect");
              box.setAttribute("width", size);
              box.setAttribute("height", size);
              box.setAttribute("fill", color1);
              box.setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid black");
              box.setAttribute("id", "pp" + number); 
              box.setAttribute("stroke", "red"); 
              box.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1"); 
              g.appendChild(box);
             
              var text = document.createSvg("text");
              text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i * numberPerSide + j));
              text.setAttribute("fill", "black");
              text.setAttribute("font-size", 156);
              text.setAttribute("x", 0);
              text.setAttribute("y", size/2);
              text.setAttribute("id", "t" + number);
              g.appendChild(text);
    
              svg.appendChild(g);
            }  
        }
        
        
        svg.addEventListener(
            "mousedown",
            function(e){
                var id = e.target.id;
                if(id)
                alert(id);

            // id grid clicked
            
                    
            // Creating the image... (not work)
            var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','20');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','20');
    img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/SVG_Simple_Logo.svg');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','10');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','10');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'id','image_test');

            var puff = document.getElementById(id); 
            puff.appendChild(img);  
            },
            false);
        return svg;
    };
    
    var tablero = document.getElementById("tablero");
    tablero.appendChild(grid(10, 500, 3000, ["#9B7653"]));

  
  //]]></script>
```

Comment: unless you really really really need one big SVG I would suggest to make the grid with CSS-grid; and the pieces with individual SVGs inside CSS grid locations. That is a whole lot easier to create and debug

Comment: Thanks! i need a big svg , i used less in the code snippet for no lag anybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image can't be the child of a rect element. It would need to have the g element as a parent i.e. be a sibling of the rect element. I've fixed that below.

So this line

```
puff.appendChild(img);
```

becomes

```
puff.parentElement.appendChild(img);
```

```html
  <body>
  <div id="tablero"  style="">
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    document.createSvg = function(tagName) {
        var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        return this.createElementNS(svgNS, tagName);
    };
    
    var numberPerSide = 20;
    var size = 10;
    var pixelsPerSide = 400;
    
    
    var eldiv = 0;
    var estado = 0;
    var tipo = "0";   
    
    // create grid
    var grid = function(numberPerSide, size, pixelsPerSide, colors) {
        var svg = document.createSvg("svg");
        svg.setAttribute("width", pixelsPerSide);
        svg.setAttribute("height", pixelsPerSide);
        svg.setAttribute("viewBox", [0, 0, numberPerSide * size, numberPerSide * size].join(" "));
        
        // create each box
        for(var i = 0; i < numberPerSide; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < numberPerSide; j++) {
              var color1 = colors[(i+j) % colors.length];
              var color2 = colors[(i+j+1) % colors.length];  
              var g = document.createSvg("g");
              g.setAttribute("transform", ["translate(", i*size, ",", j*size, ")"].join(""));
              var number = numberPerSide * i + j;
              var box = document.createSvg("rect");
              box.setAttribute("width", size);
              box.setAttribute("height", size);
              box.setAttribute("fill", color1);
              box.setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid black");
              box.setAttribute("id", "pp" + number); 
              box.setAttribute("stroke", "red"); 
              box.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1"); 
              g.appendChild(box);
             
              var text = document.createSvg("text");
              text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i * numberPerSide + j));
              text.setAttribute("fill", "black");
              text.setAttribute("font-size", 156);
              text.setAttribute("x", 0);
              text.setAttribute("y", size/2);
              text.setAttribute("id", "t" + number);
              g.appendChild(text);
    
              svg.appendChild(g);
            }  
        }
        
        
        svg.addEventListener(
            "mousedown",
            function(e){
                var id = e.target.id;
                if(id)
                alert(id);

            // id grid clicked
            
                    
            // Creating the image... (not work)
            var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','20');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','20');
    img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/SVG_Simple_Logo.svg');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','10');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','10');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');
            img.setAttributeNS(null,'id','image_test');

            var puff = document.getElementById(id);
            puff.parentElement.appendChild(img);  
            },
            false);
        return svg;
    };
    
    var tablero = document.getElementById("tablero");
    tablero.appendChild(grid(10, 500, 3000, ["#9B7653"]));

  
  //]]></script>
```